# External Jquery dependencies in Ionic 2 and Angular 2 Not Working

Tags: jquery, angular, ionic-framework, cron, ionic2

Using this technique from here (https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/12/External-JavaScript-dependencies-in-Typescript-and-Angular-2), I tried to use jquery cron (http://shawnchin.github.io/jquery-cron/) with jquery inside my ionic 2 / angular 2 mobile app.

```
import $ from 'jquery';

window["$"] = $;
window["jQuery"] = $;

export class CronPage implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
      (<any> $("#selector")).cron();
  }
}
```

And added the plugin in the index.html after the main.js

```
<script src="build/main.js"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery-cron/cron/jquery-cron.js"></script>
```

**Result:**

It showed NO ERROR whatsoever, but it did not work! The cron select controls did not appear at all.

What is still going wrong?

Comment: Can you move `(<any> $("#selector")).cron();` to afterViewInit life-cycle hook and try again?

Comment: I did but still did not work. Nothing happens and no error. Maybe the code is correct, but the function is never called.

Comment: This `CronPage` is that a component? Where is `#selector` element in your html?

Comment: `CronPage` is a component. `#selector` is inside a ion-item. `<ion-item>
       <div id="selector"></div>
     </ion-item>`

Comment: I noticed that AfterViewChecked worked but it was weird. It kept on executing the code everytime i enter the page with a mouse or i scroll, creating multiple and uncontrollable cron select controls. What do I do from here?